# Can you help me to read this YAML file?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am new to YAML. I have tried to follow a tutorial (https://www.java-success.com/yaml-java-using-snakeyaml-library-tutorial/), but it is incomplete. So far, my YAML file looks like this:

```
tests:
- class: tests.layers.DeleteCustomLayerTest
  param: layer
  value: Test Layer
- class: tests.routes.ViewRoutesTest
  param: project
  value: SNS Project Test
```

I have added snakeyaml to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have added snakeyaml-1.21.jar to me libs folder.

I have created a definition for the file called YamlTestDataFile:

```
package otherObjects;
import java.util.Map;

public class YamlTestDataFile {

    private Map<String, String> tests;

    public Map<String, String> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }

    public void setTests(Map<String, String> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }

     public Map<String, String> getTests(Map<String, String> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
        return tests;
    }
}
```

And finally, a utility to read the file:

```
package utils;

import java.io.InputStream;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import otherObjects.YamlTestDataFile;

public class ReadYamlTestData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YamlTestDataFile testData = null;

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

        try(InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("testData.yml")) {
        testData = yaml.loadAs(in, YamlTestDataFile.class);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    String test =  testData.getTests().get("class");
    System.out.println("test=" + test);
  }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Cannot create property=tests for JavaBean=otherObjects.YamlTestDataFile@5fdef03a
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
tests:
^
No suitable constructor with 2 arguments found for interface java.util.Map
 in 'reader', line 2, column 1:
- class: tests.layers.DeleteCust ...
```

I am afraid I haven't a clue what is going on, and cannot find any decent tutorials that explain any better.

Following on from flyx's reply, I have made some headway with this.

First, I changed the YAML file so it did not use the word class:

```
tests:
- className: tests.layers.DeleteCustomLayerTest
  param: layer
  value: Test Layer
- className: tests.routes.ViewRoutesTest
  param: project
  value: SNS Project Test
```

My YAML file definition looks like this:

```
package otherObjects;
import java.util.List;

public class YamlTestDataFile {

/* public, no-argument constructor */
public YamlTestDataFile() {

}

public static final class Test {
    private String className;
    public String param;
    public String value;

    public String getClassName() { return className; }
    public void setClassName(final String value) { className = value; }

    public String getParam() { return param; }
    public void setParam(final String value) { param = value; }

    public String getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(final String string) { param = string; }
}

private List<Test> tests;

public List<Test> getTests() {
    return tests;
}

public void setTests(List<Test> tests) {
    this.tests = tests;
}
```

}

and my reader:

```
package utils;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;

import otherObjects.YamlTestDataFile;
import otherObjects.YamlTestDataFile.Test;

public class ReadYamlTestData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Constructor constructor = new Constructor(YamlTestDataFile.class);
        TypeDescription dataDesc = new TypeDescription(YamlTestDataFile.class);
        dataDesc.putListPropertyType("tests", YamlTestDataFile.Test.class);
        constructor.addTypeDescription(dataDesc);
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
        InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("testData.yml");

        YamlTestDataFile testData = null;
        try {
            testData = yaml.loadAs(in, YamlTestDataFile.class);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Test> tests=testData.getTests();

        for (int x=0; x<tests.size(); x++)
        System.out.println(tests.get(x).getClassName() + ", " + tests.get(x).getParam() + ", " + tests.get(x).getValue());

    }
}
```

The output is pretty much what I am looking for:

```
tests.layers.DeleteCustomLayerTest, layer, Test Layer
tests.routes.ViewRoutesTest, project, SNS Project Test
```

Comment: Am i overlooking something, or is that tests.layers.DeleteCustomLayerTest in which the error occurs ... is missing from your question? If so, please read [mcve] and further enhance your question.

Comment: no, 'tests.layers.DeleteCustomLayerTest' is part of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class defined in your code does not match the structure of the YAML data.

In your YAML file, your root is a mapping containing one key, `tests`. The value of this key is a sequence of mappings. You map this construct to a class which has a field `tests` which is a `Map<String, String>`. So you are trying to construct a Java `Map` from a YAML sequence. SnakeYaml rightfully complains that it cannot do that.

Your YAML structure looks like you want to do something like this:

```
public class YamlTestDataFile {
    public static final class Test {
        private String className;
        public String param;
        public String value;

        public String getClass() { return className; }
        public void setClass(final String value) { className = value; }
    }

    private List<Test> tests;

    public List<Test> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }

    public void setTests(List<Test> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }
}
```

Note that `class` is a keyword in Java, so we need getters and setters to load that value.

Type erasure prevents SnakeYaml to see what the generic parameter for the `tests` List is. Therefore, we need to tell it that this is a list of `Test`. Let's modify the loading code appropriately:

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(YamlTestDataFile.class);
TypeDescription dataDesc = new TypeDescription(YamlTestDataFile.class);
dataDesc.putListPropertyType("tests", YamlTestDataFile.Test.class);
constructor.addTypeDescription(dataDesc);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("testData.yml");
testData = yaml.loadAs(in, YamlTestDataFile.class);
```

Hint: Code untested.

Comment: Thanks flyx. That looks very useful. Is that Constructor meant to be org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor and TypeDescription org.yaml.snakeyaml.TypeDescription?

Comment: Yes. See also [the SnakeYaml documentation about TypeDescription](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections).